# Give a user permissions to start, stop or restart shiny-server

Tags: permissions, sudo, r, rstudio

I need to give permission to a user to start, stop and restart Rstudio's shiny-server.

Right now, I have been managing the service upon this user's request with `sudo service restart shiny-server`, but now I want the user to manage this.

My first approach to this problem is to edit the `/etc/sudoers`. But I realized I have no idea what the full path of `shiny-server` is, so I have no idea what to put in the `/etc/sudoers` file. I would have hoped to find it in `/etc/init.d/`, but that isn't the case.

Does anyone have experience with this or a work-around?

I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (Xenial Xerus) on this server.

The version of R is 3.4.1 and it was compiled from source.

Comment: Did my solution work for you? If you're getting an error then can your run the command `which service` and tell me the result. I can then update my answer to make sure it works.

Comment: This solution does work and my user is happy now! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need the filepath for shiny-server.

You should be able to give the user the required permissions by adding the following line to your `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
username ALL=(root) service restart shiny-server, service stop shiny-server, service start shiny-server
```

After adding that line, the other user should be able to run `sudo service restart shiny-server` (as well as start/stop. If you're intent on finding the init script locations, the normal locations to look are:

```
/etc/init
/etc/init.d
/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf
/etc/default
```

(found via [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/713324/how-to-find-the-file-location-of-int-d-scripts-in-ubuntu) question)

Comment: You would need the path for `service` to be listed , eg `/sbin/service`.

Comment: `sudo visudo /etc/sudoers` says that adding this line adds a syntax error. Any idea why?